# Django get_or_create() duplicates in db

Tags: python, django

Using `Django 1.11.6`, `MySql`
I`m importing uniq only data rows from **CSV** file (~530 rows).
After 1st import - all 530 records updated to the DB.
If I import this file 2d time and **~30** last records will be updated to DB.

Get data:

```
obj.account = int(ready_item[0].replace("\"","").replace("*",""))
                pai_obj.reporting_mask = str(ready_item[0].replace("\"","").replace("*",""))
                pai_obj.group = ready_item[1].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.location = ready_item[2].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.terminal = ready_item[4].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.settlement_type = ready_item[5].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.settlement_date = datetime_or_none(report_data)
                pai_obj.amount = float_or_none(ready_item[6].replace("\"","").replace("$","").replace(",",""))

                data.append(pai_obj)
```

Import vie get_or_create():

```
for record in data:
Accountmode.objects.get_or_create(
    account=record.account, 
    reporting_mask=record.reporting_mask, 
    group=record.group, 
    location=record.location, 
    terminal=record.terminal, 
    settlement_type=record.settlement_type, 
    amount=record.amount, 
    defaults={'settlement_date': record.settlement_date})
```

The Model:

```
class Accountmode(models.Model):
    account = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    reporting_mask = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    settlement_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    terminal = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=True)
    settlement_type = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

1. As I know, `get_or_create()` should check if data already exist first and create new record if Not. Why `get_or_create()` pass some records?

Comment: Mysql in READ-COMMITTED

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you have `created_date` field with default `datetime.now` and it's always at least by a fraction of second different. Is this column "duplicated" in the database as well  or is it always different?

Comment: It works the same with / or without defaults. :(
DateTime.now sets automatically after Getting checking completes.

Answer (score 0):

The case was about Flout values with +3 symbols after come (12,012).
Those values were duplicating each time the user import same file.
Next solution was found:
1. Save amount and other values at `str` during file rows parsing.

```
obj.account = int(ready_item[0].replace("\"","").replace("*",""))
                pai_obj.reporting_mask = str(ready_item[0].replace("\"","").replace("*",""))
                pai_obj.group = ready_item[1].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.location = ready_item[2].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.terminal = ready_item[4].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.settlement_type = ready_item[5].replace("\"","")
                pai_obj.settlement_date = datetime_or_none(report_data)
                pai_obj.amount = *str*(ready_item[6].replace("\"","").replace("$","").replace(",",""))

                data.append(pai_obj)
```